# Verilog: use array element in hierarchical path

Tags: arrays, verilog, system-verilog

My question is about how to use predefined array element in hierarchical path in Verilog (SystemVerilog).

So for example I have defined the following string array:

```
string my_modules [0:1] = {"my_module_0","my_module_1"};
```

After, in my code I try to use them in some hierarchy:

```
generate
for (genvar i = 0; i < 2; i++) begin: BLOCK
    wire a = top_module.my_modules[i].a;
end
endgenerate
```

But I'm getting simulation error, because it cannot find the hierarchy as it is looking for `my_modules` module instead of its defined value (i.e `my_module_0` and `my_module_1`).

Can someone advise on this ?

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot use strings to form variable pathnames in SystemVerilog. If you could show more of what you are trying to accomplish, we might able to suggest an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

I tried with NCVerilog and the result is ok with small modification.

```
generate
for (genvar i = 0; i < 2; i++) begin: BLOCK
    wire a = top_module.my_modules[i][0];
end
endgenerate
```

1. There is no `my_modules[i].a`. How could a string type has a sub-field `a`?
2. I append `[0]` to `my_modules[i]` because `my_modules[i]` is a string type.

Comment: This compiles at least in cadence xcelium too... thanks

Comment: Actually in elaboration there's a hierarchical lookup failure with this code unfortunately...